User-friendly way of displaying booleans in a custom field
I'm enabling the average user to add custom fields in a form. These fields can be strings, numbers, or booleans.

To be user-friendly, I think I should rename String to Text. What about Boolean? What should I name it, and what labels should I give them? On and Off?
Or maybe I should use a switch? I chose a select input because the key and type inputs looked better.

Could you add the mockup for the switch concept? Do you mean switch everywhere or just the 'Type' field?

Maybe you can use the approach that figma is using to assign values and type, to variables. That approach has been really helpful to non-tech users to use and work with variables. Another recommendation that I have is, assign first the type of the variable and then assign its value.
I'm assuming you're working for a metadata site, so you can take a different approach and that's why @Ren was asking for a mockup, because it is hard to answer if you don't have the context.

On the image above I'm proposing to define first the type since I believe is the mental model that any programmer follows and then assign its value. You can also move that to the first column and then define the key to finally define the value, however as I mentioned if you have a metadata dictionary it is helpful to first see the key and then the type.
‍

Yes, my form looks exactly like that. But instead of true and false, I used a green check and a gray x. Like the bottom right ones: https://cdn.thedesignerstoolbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/toggle-switch-ui-examples.png

You can add the labels true and false to give more context to your users. It might be not clear enough for them what is the meaning, you should reduce friction and misinterpretations.
